# Rabbitmq installation error : Applying plugin configuration to rabbit@... failed. * Could not contact node rabbit@

Tags: rabbitmq

I am new to RabbitMq .I am installing the rabbitmq on my system .while running this command  `rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management`  i am getting an error like

```
'call "C:\Program Files\erl7.2.1\bin\erl.exe" -A0 -noinput -boot start_clean -ev
al "net_kernel:start([list_to_atom(""rabbit-gethostname-"" ++ os:getpid()), shor
tnames]), [_, H] = string:tokens(atom_to_list(node()), ""@""), io:format(""~s~n"
", [H]), init:stop()."' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Plugin configuration unchanged.

Applying plugin configuration to rabbit@... failed.
 * Could not contact node rabbit@.
   Changes will take effect at broker restart.
 * Options: --online  - fail if broker cannot be contacted.
            --offline - do not try to contact broker.
```

Can any one help me to solve this error ?

Answer (score 0):

try to reinstall erlang and check Microsoft's DLL Component.

[image]